# No implicit conversion of nil into String. dbview_cti

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, class-table-inheritance

I use [dbview_cti](https://github.com/mvdamme/dbview_cti) gem to make Class Table Inheritance (CTI). I have two classes Person(abstract class) and Client(inherits Person).

Problem:

When I try make `rake db:migrate`, console write this error:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    no implicit conversion of nil into String ../postgresql/utils.rb:24:in `quote_ident'
```

Model Person

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  cti_base_class
end
```

Model Client

```
class Client < Person
  cti_derived_class
end
```

Migration create_people

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :persons do |t|
      t.string :pesel, null: false
      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.date :data_of_birth, null: false
      t.string :password_digest, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :persons
  end
end
```

Migration create_clients

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.references :person
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    cti_create_view('Client')
  end
end
```

More details about error:

```
>     == 20160223135814 CreateClients: migrating ====================================
>     -- create_table(:clients)
>        -> 0.0348s
>     -- cti_create_view("Client")
>     rake aborted!
>     StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>     
>     no implicit conversion of nil into String/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb:24:in
> `quote_ident'
>     /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb:24:in
> `quoted'
>     /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:31:in
> `quote_table_name'
>     /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:738:in `column_definitions'
>     /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:186:in
> `columns'
>     /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in
> `columns'
```

Any idea where is wrong?

Comment: Try removing abstract_class from Person, my guess is it is trying to get table_name from the cti_base_class and marking it as abstract makes it nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Person` class is marked as an abstract class and as such its `table_name` is `nil`. In general abstract_class has been added so gems can define their own subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base that can be then inherited in the application without causing STI logic to get in. You can either make it non-abstract or set back the table name for inheritance:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = 'people'
  cti_base_class
end
```